# How can I pad all equal signs in Python except for ==, !=, >=, <=?

Tags: python

If I do a simple:

```
str.replace('=', ' = ')
```

it will pad ALL equal signs. But I want to leave `==`, `!=`, `>=`, `<=`, `+=`, `-=`, `/=`, `*=` in tact.

Comment: Have you tried using regular expressions?

Comment: \* **intact**. You should look into https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re.

Comment: Is this about code style and conforming to PEP8? if yes, you could look at black https://github.com/python/black

Comment: No, in fact, I want to specifically go against some PEP8 standards

Comment: why/how? can you give a bit more context to your issue?

Comment: I am doing some code parsing experiments, and currently `stuff=5` is treated as one token. I want to split it to `stuff = 5`, so that it will be treated as 3 tokens

Comment: right but `stuff = 5` *is* conforming to PEP8 though, so why do you say this is against PEP8?

Comment: Actually the rules might be a bit more complicated, whitespace is recommended around `=` generally https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations, but not i think in the case of keyword arguments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
re.sub(r'(?<![=!<>+-\/\*])(\=)(?![=!<>+-\/\*])', ' = ', s)
```

---

Example:

```
import re
s = 'a=d==a!=s=as<=s 5-=10 5=+4=!a'
re.sub(r'(?<![=!<>+-\/\*])(\=)(?![=!<>+-\/\*])', ' = ', s)
# 'a = d==a!=s = as<=s 5-=10 5=+4=!a'
```

---

Breakdown:

> (?+-/*])(\=)(?![=!<>+-/*])

- Negative Lookbehind `(?<![=!<>+-\/\*])`

  - Assert that the Regex below does not match
  - `=!<>` matches a single character in the list `=!<>` (case sensitive)
  - `+-\/` a single character in the range between `+` (index 43) and `/` (index 47) (case sensitive)
  - `\*` matches the character * literally (case sensitive)
- 1st Capturing Group `(\=)`

  - `\=` matches the character = literally (case sensitive)
- Negative Lookahead `(?![=!<>+-\/\*])`

  - Assert that the Regex below does not match
  - Match a single character present in the list below `[=!<>+-\/\*]`
  - `=!<>` matches a single character in the list `=!<>` (case sensitive)
  - `+-\/` a single character in the range between + (index 43) and / (index 47) (case sensitive)
  - `\*` matches the character * literally (case sensitive)

Comment: This would also keep `=>` , `=<` , `=+`, `=-` as same. Shouldn't `=` be padded in these cases?

Comment: I guess I should also add `*=`, `/=`, `%=`, `**=`, `//=` to the list

Comment: The current solution also contemplates these cases @Shamoon updated the example